# Поиск строки в памяти процесса Java

Tags: c#, winapi, memory, pinvoke

Доброе время суток.
У меня есть процесс Java, в котором содержится строка.
При дампе всех строк при помощи CheatEngine, эта строка там имеется.
Но когда я пытаюсь провести дамп при помощи кода на C#, эта строка там не обнаруживается.
Использую вот этот туториал: http://www.codingvision.net/security/c-how-to-scan-a-process-memory

```
        SYSTEM_INFO sys_info = new SYSTEM_INFO();
        GetSystemInfo(out sys_info);

        IntPtr proc_min_address = sys_info.minimumApplicationAddress;
        IntPtr proc_max_address = sys_info.maximumApplicationAddress;

        long proc_min_address_l = (long)proc_min_address;
        long proc_max_address_l = (long)proc_max_address;

        Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("java")[0];

        IntPtr processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_WM_READ, false, process.Id);


        MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mem_basic_info = new MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION();

        int bytesRead = 0;

        var bList = new List<byte>();

        while (proc_min_address_l < proc_max_address_l)
        {
            label1.Invoke((Action)delegate
            {
                label1.Text =
                    $"{proc_min_address}/{proc_max_address} | {proc_min_address_l}/{proc_max_address_l}";
            });

            VirtualQueryEx(processHandle, proc_min_address, out mem_basic_info, 28);

            if (mem_basic_info.Protect == PAGE_READWRITE && mem_basic_info.State == MEM_COMMIT)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[mem_basic_info.RegionSize];

                ReadProcessMemory((int)processHandle, mem_basic_info.BaseAddress, buffer, mem_basic_info.RegionSize, ref bytesRead);

                for (int i = 0; i < mem_basic_info.RegionSize; i++)
                {
                    bList.Add(buffer[i]);
                }
            }

            proc_min_address_l += mem_basic_info.RegionSize;
            proc_min_address = new IntPtr(proc_min_address_l);
        }

        var s = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bList.ToArray());

        if (s.Contains("<:>"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Found!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not found!");
        }
```

Подскажите, как исправить мой код, что бы тот правильно искал все строки в памяти приложения?

Comment: Ух, `label1.Invoke` и `VirtualQueryEx` в одном методе.

Comment: Да, быдлокод такой быдлокод. Сделано для дебага, что бы визуально видеть насколько прогресс ушел.

Comment: Из [этого ответа](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9699224/276994): At the JVM level, if you are using `-XX:+UseCompressedStrings` (which is default for some updates of Java 6) The actual in-memory representation can be 8-bit, ISO-8859-1 but only for strings which do not need UTF-16 encoding.

Comment: То есть если ваша строка на уровне языка содержит лишь ASCII, то она может быть закодирована и как ASCII.

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не знаю, в какой кодировке строка.

Comment: Я перепробовал все доступные в .net кодировки. Безрезультатно.

Comment: Ну это понятно, но откуда ж мы знаем? Либо в UTF-16, либо в ISO-8859-1, исходя из процитированного ответа.

Comment: Не, ваш код не будет работать в случае произвольной кодировки. Вы почему-то декодируете **всю память** как строку. Это неправильно. Лучше наоборот, закодируйте вашу строку в байты, и ищите эти байты в памяти. (Вам придётся сделать это дважды — в Unicode и в ISO-8859-1.)

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Буду пробовать.

Comment: Дамп в файл, там ищите вашу строку в HIEW. Если в файле нашли, а софтина нет - уже сможете отлаживаться.